# How to address shortcomings of associated model from Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the [getting started tutorial for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model) which was fine for the most part, but lacked some detail when it came to the associated model (comments):

1. There was no validation - it's easy enough to add that, but then I wasn't sure how to display the error messages from failed validation.
2. Using `@article.comments.build` so you can display the comment form effectively "created" another comment in that session, so if you iterate through all comments, there'd be an extra blank one because of that. It's just a coincidence that the guide listed the comments *before* that line of code was executed, and thus didn't encounter the problem.

Whilst I tried something for 1. (which will be detailed below), I've no idea how to go about solving 2. - it probably belongs in its own question, but I'm not even sure how to name it.

**Attempt at validation/error display**

I tried to basically apply the same strategy for displaying error messages with the articles, again for the comments. I knew there'd be some extra complexity, but I tried to navigate it logically. This is what I changed:

app/models/comments.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  validates :commenter, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create 
    @article = Post.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'articles/show'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    ...
```

app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <% if self.instance_variable_defined?('@comment') and @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, 'error') %> occurred:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter, 'Your Name' %>
    ...
```

Whilst this successfully displayed the error messages, the following problems occurred:

1. Because it uses render instead of redirect, the user ends up on a URL that normally can't serve `GET` requests (i.e. /posts/1/comments) - this is strange, because if the page loads again it'll 404. I can't use redirect though, because then the attempted comment creation (with the error messages) will be lost.
2. Presumably because `@article.comments.new` has been executed prior to rendering, the same problem as that which was described in 2. above (regarding `@article.comments.build`) occurs: a blank comment is displayed.

So that's where I'm stuck. These are pretty basic problems - the system wouldn't be whole without them, and yet I'm lost for what the proper solution would be.

**How can I display these errors whilst avoiding the above problems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @evedovelli's use of `flash`, but solving the problems it had (as mentioned in that answer's comments), I ended up using:

- `flash[:comment_errors] = @comment.errors.full_messages` to communicate the error messages themselves across the redirect. I couldn't flash the `@comment` or `@comment.errors` because they ended up as hashes instead of instances of their original objects, and thus lost their useful methods, whereas `full_messages` is simply an array and thus was communicated in its entirety.
- `form_for([@post, Comment.new]) do |f|` (as opposed to `@post.comments.new/build`). That new comment is not immediately linked to the `@post`, and therefore won't appear in `@post.comments.all`. The form still worked, though - submissions would create the comment under only that post. However I feel like this is still just avoiding the real problem: if I tried looping through all comments for some reason, then that new, unsaved comment would be found again.

After writing that `form_for` part:

> then the new, unsaved comment would be found again

I realised that I'd stumbled across some potential search terms (where I couldn't quite find the words for that problem before)! So I searched `rails collection get saved only`, which led to `rails activerecord get persisted` and came up with the following useful methods:

- [`persisted?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F)
- [`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F)

These can be used to properly solve the second problem: by specifically ignoring records which have not yet been saved, only where appropriate. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution for displaying the errors is correct. When you render the `articles/show` instead of redirect, like you figured out, you end up in the `/posts/:id/comments` because that is your current path for the HTTP method POST that was just called.

To get errors displayed and to redirect to the `new` path you can make some changes to your code:

1) In the create action:

```
if @comment.save
  flash[:comment] = nil
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
else
  flash[:comment] = @comment
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

2) In the show article action:

```
@comment = flash[:comment] || @article.comments.build
```

3) In the article show view, replace the `form_for` line with:

```
<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

And then your can user your code to show the errors:

```
  <% if self.instance_variable_defined?('@comment') and @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, 'error') %> occurred:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This solution may solve the 2nd problem you ran into as well.

Please let me know and help you if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. Problem 2. still exists, and it doesn't actually display error messages anymore. Note that I had to change `@comment = flash[:comment] || ...` to `if flash[:comment] @comment = Comment.new(flash[:comment]) else ...` because it wouldn't work at all otherwise - the comment would just be a hash instead of an instance of `Comment`.

Comment: I suspect that I can simply `flash` the full error messages themselves, instead of the whole comment. But is there a more "rails" approach for this?